# Changing frame of button with arc4random?

Tags: ios, swift, arc4random

I have a UIButton. I want it to generate at random places on the screen. It returns no errors, and runs, but nothing shows up on the screen. I tried hard-coding the values, and that works. I am using Swift.

**CODE:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let changingPoint = UIButton()
    let dot = UIImage(named: "sponsor-dot.png")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        changingPoint.setImage(dot, forState: .Normal)
        changingPoint.addTarget(self, action: "pointPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        changingPoint.frame = CGRectMake(CGFloat(arc4random()%(320)), CGFloat(arc4random()%(568)), 150, 150)

        self.view.addSubview(changingPoint)
    }

    func pointPressed(sender: UIButton!) {
        changingPoint.frame = CGRectMake(CGFloat(arc4random()%(320)), CGFloat(arc4random()%(568)), 150, 150)
        println()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: How big is your image? Given the values you're passing to arc4random, the button could be partially off the screen (or right at the edge of the screen), and you won't see it if your image is considerably smaller than 150 x 150.

Answer (score 1):

I Believe that you not set a background color for the button.

```
changingPoint.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor() //or any other color that you want
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your image is loading properly. Try printing dot to see if it is null:

```
println("image: \(dot)")
```